# How to get get bands value from geotif OPENLAYERS

Tags: javascript, maps, openlayers, geoserver

I want to show red band values from geo tiff hosted in geoserver. I don't knwo if its possible or not

```
tiffRaster = new ol.layer.Image({
        title: 'PGA(gal)',
        source: new ol.source.ImageWMS({
            url: 'http://faml.ncn.pe:8080/geoserver/faml/wms',
            params: {
                'LAYERS': 'faml:' + f
            },
            ratio: 1,
            serverType: 'geoserver'
        }),
    });
```

I tried taking values like `tiffRaster.getView()` or `tiffRaster.getSource()` but can't find bands inside. My idea is add a click listener on geotiff to get band value and show it.

This is geoTiff in Geoserver, clicking anywhere it shows value
[image: Geotiff in geoserver]

Comment: You can get info from the WMS using GetFeatureInfo and RGBA values using forEachLayerAtPixel.  Both are used in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/getfeatureinfo-image.html and more RGBA values in https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/disable-image-smoothing.html

Comment: It helped me a lot. Thanks